# Associating the logged in user with the Photo Model

Tags: django, django-models

I basically want to associate the logged in user name with the PhotoModel by using `models.ForeignKey`. I override the safe_model in admin.py but when i execute the views.py class PhotoCreateNew(View) then it stops at `print(form)` and the form is not validated (`if form.is_valid()`) skips the entire part which was supposed to set the `request.user` as `photo.user_name` and return the empty template.

My models.py

```
class Photo(models.Model):
user_name =  models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
PLACES = (('RD','研发-R&D'),('Warehouse','仓库-Warehouse'),('Gate','门卫处-Gate Guard'),('SecondFloor','2F生产部'))
photo = models.FileField()
photo_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
date = models.DateField(auto_now="True")
quantity = models.CharField(max_length=4)
CONDITIONS = (('N','NG'), ('G', 'GOOD'))
condition =models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=CONDITIONS)
place = models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=PLACES,default='Warehouse')

def __str__(self):
    return self.photo_name
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('photo:photo_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class PhotoForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Photo
    fields =['user_name','photo','photo_name','quantity','condition','place']
    exclude= ('user_name',)
```

My admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from photo.models import Photo
from photo.models import Supplier
class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if not obj.pk:
        obj.user_name = request.user
    obj.save()


admin.site.register(Supplier,)
admin.site.register(Photo, PhotoAdmin)
```

My views.py:

```
class PhotoCreateNew(View):
form_class = PhotoForm
template_name = 'photo/photo_form.html'


def get(self, request):
    form =self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

def post(self,request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    print(request.user)
    print(form)
    if form.is_valid():  # uploader has been excluded. No more error.
        print("Przeszlo")
        photo = form.save(commit=False)  # returns unsaved instance
        photo.user_name = request.user
        print(request.user)
        photo.save()  # real save to DB.

        return redirect('photo:photo_detail')
    return render(request,self.template_name,{})
```

Comment: print `form.errors`.

Comment: Also, share the contents of `request.POST`.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to override the save_model in the admin. This will hove no effect in your views.py. Wouldn't you want to override the save method in the model?

Comment: @SachinKukreja form.errors are : <ul class="errorlist"><li>photo<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
 and request.POST content is: <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['0N5YJnTDdxln0WUXKRSE4qRqhS7NvqOh4BqV9IELF7pTo9hvY3S2XE6
Tr8mCgxke'], 'photo_name': ['77'], 'quantity': ['777'], 'condition': ['G'], 'place': ['Warehouse']}>

Comment: @ger.s.brett i saw in the documentation that it's to be override in admin.py don't know if i do it right though

Comment: There should be a file in request data then. Initialize the form class with request.POST and request.FILES.

Comment: @SachinKukreja Thanks a lot ! Now it works perfectly fine !

Answer (score 0):

After initializing the form class with request.POST and request.FILES it is working.
I had to replace :

```
form = self.form_class(request.POST)
```

with :

```
form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
```